Exercise 1 Chapter 1.6 Group Cohomology Kenneth, Special case of Lefschetz theorem
Let X be finite cw-complex, $ f:X\to X$ a map such that for $\sigma$ a cell:
$$f(\sigma) \subseteq \bigcup_{\stackrel{\tau \neq \sigma}{dim\tau \leq dim\sigma}}\tau$$
Then the Lefschetz number is $0$
$$ \Lambda(f) := \sum (-1)^i trace(f_i)$$
Were $f_i$ is the induce endomorphism in $ \frac{H_i(X)}{Torsion}$ by $f$.

My first question is how is define the induce endomorphism
$$f_i: \frac{H_i(X)}{Torsion}\to \frac{H_i(X)}{Torsion}$$
I think it is the map induce by the factor theorem since $f_*(Torsion)\subseteq Torsion$ then $Torsion \subseteq\ker \pi \circ f$ where $\pi$ is de quotien map $\pi: H_i(X)\to \frac{H_i(X)}{Torsion}$.
And the big question would be how to prove the theorem, we know that $f$ doesn't have fix points since it never send a cell to it self.

None of the above. Do you know that continuous maps induce homomorphisms of homology groups?

yes but between $H_i(X)$, mi bad i should have written $f_*$

$f$ induces a map on homology groups $H_i(X)\to H_i(X)$. This is just some homomorphism.
Now, if $g:A\to A$ is any homomorphism of an Abelian group $A$, $g$ induces a map $\overline{g}:A/T\to A/T$ where $T$ is the torsion subgroup of $A$. Why? Because there is a map $A\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}A\twoheadrightarrow A/T$ and this kills the subgroup $T$, thus inducing a map $A/T\to A/T$. Why does it kill $T$? This is really saying that $g(T)\subseteq T$. And sure, this is true: consider if $x\in T$ then there is some integer $n\neq 0$, $nx=0$, and then $0=g(nx)=ng(x)$ so $g(x)$ is a torsion element; $g(T)\subseteq T$ holds. Also note that if $A$ is finitely generated then $A/T$ is a free group and we could represent $\overline{g}$ by a square matrix; the trace of this matrix is then called the trace of $g$.
So this is just a bit of algebra, it is not really a topological theorem that there is an induced map $H_i(X)/\text{torsion}\to H_i(X)/\text{torsion}$.
